# how to parse String dateformat to only time

Tags: java

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:ms");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date finalTime=dateFormat1.parse(dateFormat.format(cal1.getTime()));
System.out.println(finalTime1);
```

**Actual output**

```
Thu Jan 01 17:01:37 IST 1970
```

**Expected Output**

```
17:01:37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` is not correct... Also note you are **not** printing the `String` with the date formatted, instead of this you are printing the `Date` object, so you will see always this format because you call `Date.toString()` method implicit when you call `System.out.println(finalTime1);`.

Use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String dateFormatted = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())
System.out.println(dateFormatted);
```

And you will get correct output...

Comment: dateFormat1.format(finalTime1); output as string how to parse into Date type